# Oracle Expired User by Date without PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME

Tags: oracle, authentication, password-protection

I have a question to Expired Oracle User in DBA_USER Table.

What does it mean when the status of an account is Open when the expiry_date is already older than current date? In my opinion expiration of the account depends of the PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME. But what happens when PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME = Unlimited?

For example (current date = 21.12.2017)

```
Expiry_date | PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME | User Expired?
01.01.2010  | 10                  | Yes (User Expired -> User is not able to login)
20.12.2017  | 10                  | No (User not Expired -> User is able to login)
01.01.2010  | Unlimited           | No User not Expired?
```

I'm right?

Comment: I assume Oracle will endlessly remind the user that he should change his password - but I am not sure about that. Did you test anything? Note, in order to get ACCOUNT_STATUS changed to `EXPIRED(GRACE)` the user must logon. Status does not change automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I assume the same, but unfortunately I can not test it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wernfried should be right Oracle will endlessly remind the user that he should change his password and only after the first login after expiry_date the ACCOUNT_STATUS is changed to EXPIRED(GRACE)